# Python and Arduino Serial Communication: send and receive

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

What I want to do is actually query Arduino to get data. When I send a command from Python to Arduino, Arduino will send back some data depending on what the query keyword is. I am able to do this but with a very low speed, I wish to have a more efficient way to do this, for example, query at least 100 times per second. Any idea? Thanks!

The code I use:

Arduino:

```
int temp=1;
char s[2];
int speedIn=0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()>0){
    Serial.readBytes(s,1);
    speedIn=int(s[0]);
    if(speedIn==49){
      Serial.println(">Data1Send<");
      speedIn=0;
      }
    else if(speedIn==50){
      Serial.print(">");
      Serial.print(temp);
      Serial.println("<");
      speedIn=0;
      }
    else{
      Serial.println(">Wrong Data<");
      speedIn=0;
      }
    }
    if(temp<300){
      temp=temp+1;
      }
    //delay(100);
}
```

Python:

```
import serial
import time

if __name__=="__main__":
    sc = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1421',timeout=None,baudrate=115200)
    sc.flush()
    while True:
        #s=raw_input()
        s=str(50)
        if len(s) >0:
            if s.isdigit():
                sc.write(chr(int(s)))
                time.sleep(1.0)
                if sc.inWaiting()>0:
                    print(sc.read(sc.inWaiting()))
```

If I change the time delay in Python from 1.0sec to 0.1sec, it will not work any more (no data can be received and just in waiting state).

Comment: You mentioned that it doesn't work when sleeping for less time. What happens?

Comment: When sleeping for less time, then no data can be received in Python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your python code does this:

1. Send a command
2. Sleep for some time (presumably to give the arduino time to reply)
3. Read the reply
4. If no reply, repeat from step 1

You mentioned that it doesn't work if the sleep period is too short. I wonder if the following could be happening. Imagine there were no sleep period. The python code will immediately check for a reply, which may not exist because the arduino hasn't had time to respond. In that case, it will immediately try to send another command. This could keep happening repeatedly--the python code could essentially flood the line with requests that the arduino can't keep up with. You prevent this from happening using the sleep period, but the sleep period probably takes longer than the arduino actually needs, which would reduce your data rate.

If that's the case, it might work to do this in the python code instead:

1. Send a command
2. Wait for the arduino to reply (but not using sleep). Ideally, use a read command that blocks until input is received. A less preferable alternative is to busywait--enter a loop that does nothing but check whether a reply has been received and terminates when input is available.
3. Read the reply
4. Repeat from step 1